# update solr index by nutch

Tags: solr, nutch

I am using nutch 1.5 and solr 3.5. I would like to know the best way to update solr index through nutch. The seedlist.txt in nutch contains about a million urls. New urls will be added daily. Also, some of the urls will be removed or updated.

The nutch command "./nutch crawl urls -solr /solr/ -dir crawl -depth 1 -topN 10" will pickup the newly added urls for indexing. However, the updated and removed urls will not be touched at all.

By removing the crawl folder and re-index again will fix the "add" and "update" issue. However, it will take a long time to crawl a million urls as well as the "remove" urls index are still in Solr.

The only want I know to remove Solr index is use the update command like "update?commit=true&stream.body=id:xxxx".

Am I in the correct direction ? or there is a better way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

you will almost certainly need to inject new urls into an existing crawldb ( lookup bin/nutch inject), you can also issue a bin/nutch readdb ... -dump dumpfolder - this will show you how long it will be until those old urls are crawled again.

Answer (score 0):

You can alter settings for urls that have become inactive or deleted so when you attempt to re-crawl them it marks them as DB_GONE.  Altering this setting will then delete these urls based on your own choices.

```
<property>
  <name>db.update.purge.404</name>
  <value>true</value>
  <description>If true, updatedb will add purge records with status DB_GONE
  from the CrawlDB.
  </description>
</property>
```

Check out http://amac4.blogspot.com/2013/08/nutch-re-crawling.html for more details